# How can I get the input selected on a Autocomplete field when onKeyPress

Tags: reactjs, material-ui

How do I get the value of the autocomplete field when the user press the "Enter" key ?

Here's the code for the Autocomplete :

```
<Autocomplete
              freeSolo
              id="streetName"
              getOptionLabel={(option) => option.name}
              options={streetsName}
              onChange={(event, newValue) => {
                if (newValue !== null) {
                  setSelectedStreetName({
                    generique: newValue.generique,
                    specifique: newValue.specifique,
                    particule: newValue.particule,
                  });
                }
              }}
              onKeyDown={(e, value) => {
                if (e.key === 'Enter') handleClick(value);
              }}
              renderInput={(params) => (
                <TextField
                  {...params}
                  error={error}
                  fullWidth
                  label="Rue"
                  required
                  size="small"
                  variant="outlined"
                />
              )}
            />
```

The value doesn't hold anything here!

Thank you !

Comment: onSelect() / onChange() events should save the selected value to the control state.
then, you can take the state under onKeyDown event.

Answer (score -2):

This is likely available at:

```
              onKeyDown={(e) => {
                if (e.key === 'Enter') handleClick(e.target.value);
              }}
```

Answer (score -2):

```
<Autocomplete
  onKeyDown={(e) => {
    const code = e.keyCode || e.which;

    if (code === 13) {
      // or e.key === 'Enter'
      handleClick(e.target.value);
    }
  }}
  ...
/>
```

Comment: Ok so the problem with that code is that I don't get the complete value of the selected option. All I get is the incomplete input i started to input in the Autocomplete field. Is there a way to get the selected input ?

Comment: Not sure what you exactly want. What point do you press Enter key? You should able to set state like `value` and `setValue` and then you should keep the changing value using `onChange` props. Then you can use `value` when you key press.